# Calculate average of: max based on unique value in another column Excel pivot and PowerBI

Tags: pivot, max, powerbi, unique, average

I've built a process which results in a table on SQL Server with data as seen in the image below which is then connected to Excel/PowerBI for reporting.

[Dept Lvl 1 is the highest in the hierarchy and goes lower to the right with Prod Lvl 2 being the lowest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AES9H.jpg)

[image]

I need to calculate the Max 'Avail' based on unique values in 'Part' which can then be used to calculate the average/percentage. Irrespective of which hierarchical level the users try to see the data.

For Ex:
At prod lvl 2 for P3a it would be 0% as none of the 'Part' are available. (Note: at this level, values in 'Part' will be unique)
At prod lvl 1 for P3 it'd be 50% as 3 out of 6 unique parts are available.
At Dept Lvl 2 for 1B it'd be 66.66% as 4 out of 6 unique parts are available. and
At Dept Lvl 1 for 1 it'd be 83.33% as 5 out of 6 unique parts are available.

I need to publish this on PowerBI and also on Excel for external users without access to PowerBI. I'm new to PowerBI but have been working on Excel for sometime now however, I am unable to figure out how to calculate this on either one. Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Still not able to do this on Excel but a colleague helped me out with PowerBI and this formula worked
Availability = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_PART_AVAIL[PART]),VW_PART_AVAIL[AVAIL]>0) / DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_PART_AVAIL[PART])

Comment: Figured out how to do this on Excel today. Below Calculated field created through Power Pivot seemed to work
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_PART_AVAIL[PART]), FILTER(VW_PART_AVAIL,VW_PART_AVAIL[AVAIL]>0))/DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_PART_AVAIL[PART])